# How to convert .abs to .txt, and read it into R

Tags: r, text, abstract, notepad

I have over 1,000 files with the .abs extension (abstracts). I need to read it into R.

Is there a way I can either (i) import .abs files directly into R or (ii) batch convert these files into .txt, then import into R? I have googled but seem to find no answer.

P/S: I am able to open the files to view using notepad, but the file extension is still .abs. The objective is to import into R.

Comment: Try `?readLines`, file name extensions don't matter.